# Changing Admin Panel Navigation bar Position

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchardcms-1.7

By Default in Orchard CMS, navigation bar is aligned to left as shown in picture on the below link. Is this possible to aligned to top or change its navigation theme to something else?

http://tinypic.com/r/t7zsls/8

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to change the layout of the admin menu. To do this you will need to modify Layout.cshtml and Menu.cshtml to your liking.

From your screenshot it looks like you are using the default TheAdmin theme so that is where you could locate these views.